# How do I revert a file to 'last checkin' state in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, undo

I have a hypothetical Mercurial repository on disc. I'm most of the way through creating a new feature, when I realise I've made a complete mess of the file I'm working on, and want to revert that file back to its last commit state.

I can use `hg update` to refresh the working copy from the repository, but that updates every file.

Is there a mercurial command that can update just a single file?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is a mercurial command to revert files. `hg revert` this should revert any changes. You can also pass a file name to it e.g `hg revert fileName`.

Answer (score 15):

`hg revert fileName` will revert that file back to the revision you are at.
If you want to revert all changes you can run `hg revert --all`.

Both of these will produce fileName.orig files so you can keep the changes you are wanting to revert just in case.  If you want to revert the file and not have all the .orig files you can add the `-C` option:
`hg revert fileName -C`
`hg revert --all -C`

Comment: I find it better to add `*.orig` to my `.hgignore` file and then just leave the `.orig` files around. Maybe I'll need them one day :) If they bother you, then you can use the purge extension to clean them up.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you can type `hg revert /path/to/file/<file name>` and it will just update that file.

Comment: Nope, that's Git that has this weird behavior for `git checkout` (in Mercurial, `hg checkout` is an alias for `hg update`).